# what is best way to Prevent From Being Hooked in simultaneous requests

Tags: php, mysql

by sending  simultaneous requests  to a php page (We assume all this requests received by php  at the same time) we can inject repeated data in mysql before Analyzing the "correct" endpoint by php (because all request is receiving in same time;thus php for all requests check Allowing  to insert in mysql  in one time(while only one of requests actually was allowed to insert).
After receiving all responses from mysql at a time,php sent several inserting requests  for mysql
but only one is valid
How To Prevent From Being Hooked in simultaneous requests(without adding unique key in table fields)

Answer (score 0):

You can try locking the table with `LOCK TABLES` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html

Or use `sem_get()` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sem-get.php to use semaphores in PHP, if your server can make use of them.